# Inserting a div

Tags: css

First, I apologize if this question has been asked before.  I'm really not sure what to search for and I am at a loss even trying to explain this.  I will be as clear as I can.

I want a page of 10-20 thumbnail images.  Each image will be in a div for padding.  The size of the images is unknown, but the width of the container will be a set value, let's say 1000px.  I want the images floated so that they line up left to right.

I want to insert a div after the first row of images.  This div will span the width of the container.  The images will continue after this div.  Since I am unsure how wide the images will be, I am unsure how many images will be in the first row.  I want the browser to render as many items as will fit in the first row, then the advert div, then continue with the items.  Is this even possible?

Again, sorry for not knowing how to ask this question, or if it is a duplicate.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Please provide a starting point in CodePen or JSFiddle, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This is possible,

Use CSS, the two properties ( for all divs ) are:

```
    float:    right;
    position: relative;
```

For further info look at w3schools css attributes for div.

Comment: this doesn't help at all, read again the question :),  wich is more like, how can i add a spanning box after each row drawn ... where numbers of elements can varie and is unknown ?

Answer (score 0):

No. This cannot be done with CSS. You will either need to insert all that manually, use javascript to render it in the browser, or use a server side language to do that before sending the page.

How to do any of that is too broad of an answer for SO.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it does not sound like the best idea to not have any control over the size of your elements.

I don't quite understand your scenario, because you do not provide any code, but from my understanding, the below should work.

You say the container should be 1000px.
If you set an absolute width on your images, you should be able to figure out how many elements will be displayed per row.

If your images are 100px wide, has a padding of 10px per side and a margin of 10px per side. 100 + 20 + 20 = 140px per image * 7 = 980px.

This way you know you can only display 7 elements before manually inserting the div between the rows.

If you are looping results from a database via PHP you could do something like this:

```
<?php

$i = 0;
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  if($i >= 7) {
   echo '<div class="between">bla bla bla</div>';
   $i = 0;
  } else {
   echo '<div class="img-wrap">';
   echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" />';
   echo '</div>';
   $i++;
  }
}


?>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWQzLV